# Access Denied when trying to select a Visual Studio 2017 Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have been using Visual Studio for ages, version after version. Lately I installed VS.2017 but every time I try to install a tool or extension things go wrong. I am using a restricted (non-admin) account **as I always have**.

1. Select Tools in the menu bar at the top
2. Select Extensions and Updates in the drop down menu
3. Try to select any from the list

When I do that I get a very informative dialog that only says "**Access Denied**" and nothing else. As a result I cannot install any extensions. In some cases after doing that then I cannot start VS anymore without getting "Unknown Error" which luckily I got rid of thanks to another post in SO.

Why is this happening in the new VS 2017? I never had any problem installing extensions or updates while running a Restricted User Account.

Comment: Big, big changes in the way extensions are installed.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know you are having problems.

Comment: I have done that all the times it has happened. I find VS.2017 a bit unstable yet.